# Drawing a part of a texture in opengl (android)

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

Im trying to find a way to draw a part of a texture in opengl (for example, in a sprite I need to draw different parts of the image) and I cant find it. In the questions I have been looking into, people talk about the glDrawTexfOES but from what I understand its a short way to draw a rectangle texture.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried setting texture coordinates to what you need?

Comment: @MaticOblak Do you mean the coordinates that you write next to the vertices? You can change that in run time? And does it scales the texture or slice it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, those texture coordinates are the ones.. You can change them at runtime but I'd need some info of your pipeline how and where do you push vertex and texture coordinates to GL. If you do that every frame with something like "glTexCoordPointer" you just need your buffer not to be constant and change values whenever you want. If you use some GPU buffers you will need to retrieve buffer pointer and change the values. In both cases it would be wise to do that on same thread as your "draw" method.